# Spring FileInputStream buffer sporadically contains incorrect characters

Tags: java, spring, file-io, spring-mvc, arrays

I am using FileInputStream in Spring MVC to read a chunk of a file into a byte[] buffer.

I then write (using FileCopyUtils.copy) the buffer to the response stream.

I notice that the response that is written to the stream (what the user receives) looks similar to the file, but there are blemishes.

1. before the file data, there is a '2000' (without quotes) at the top of the file.
2. this '2000' string is sporadically present throughout my file
3. The file ends with a '0'

none of these exist in the original file that is being read from. Can anyone help me get rid of these so that I have an accurate output stream?

here's an example of what my incorrect ouput looks like:

```
2000
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line o
2000
f data
a line of data
2000

a line of data
a line of data
0
```

it should just be:

```
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
a line of data
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is that the stream is specified as a [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and your simply reading it as is

Comment: Thanks. How do I change this encoding? I am currently testing from fiddler. Is there a request header that I need to add? I am specifying: User-Agent:Fiddler Host:localhost:8443 Content-Length: 109 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Follow up: Or do I not need to change this encoding? Is it just a Fiddler false-positive? Will my application know how to handle the response if I leave the encoding as is? I'm writing an iOS application and am wondering if the NSURLConnection API has support for this. Seems like it should. Anyways. Thanks for the comment. +1

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with FileInputStream. This is occurring during transmission to the client. Probably chunked encoding as suggested by ratchet freak. Use an HttpURLConnection at the client and itnwill handle that invisibly to you.

Comment: +1 thanks. Answer goes to ratchet freak for being first, but I appreciate the response. Any familiarity with iOS? Do you know if NSURLConnection supports encoding type chunked?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [IOUtils.copy()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)?

```
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream("some.file"), servletResponse.getOutputStream());
```

Hard to tell from your code, but most likely you have a bug somewhere while copying data from one place to another (index mismatch/missing flush, etc.) Use ready-made and well-tested stream copying routine to pinpoint the problem.